# Ruby sqlite3 gem fails to compile on WSL

Tags: c, ruby, sqlite, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### tl;dr:

sqlite3 is failing to compile its native extensions in a WSL Ubuntu environment, where it does not fail on an otherwise non-WSL Ubuntu native environment.

### Summary:

I've got a WSL2 install running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Windows 10 Pro (19042.1288). I have a working rbenv environment with both Ruby 2.7.4 and Ruby 3.0.2 installed. At gem native extension compile-time (`gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`) it spits out a ton of warnings and errors, but the first real error is this one:

```
sqlite3.c:33:37: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
   33 | #   define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
      |                                     ^~
```

### What I've Tried

#### Package Updates

I've updated the packages I've been told are relevant:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

#### Install Flags

I've tried running with the `--with-sqlite3-include` flag like so:

```sh
$ gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/include
```

#### Install sqlite3 from source

This results in a working install of sqlite3 from source (which is correctly loaded in the `$PATH`) but does not change the errors at gem native extension compile time.

```sh
$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-autoconf-3360000.tar.gz
$ tar xvf sqlite-autoconf-3360000.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3360000
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

#### Just Doing It On A Real Ubuntu Machine™

This works fine. This is part of what leads me to believe the issue is WSL-related. (Creating a fresh WSL Ubuntu instance yields the same issue, so I don't think it's my environment)

### The Error Log

```
$ gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Fetching sqlite3-1.4.2.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/bin/ruby -I /home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20211105-14591-ztfaj2.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... no
checking for rb_integer_pack()... no
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
make DESTDIR\= clean

current directory: /home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
make DESTDIR\=
compiling aggregator.c
compiling backup.c
compiling database.c
database.c: In function ‘rb_sqlite3_open_v2’:
database.c:38:9: warning: unused variable ‘flags’ [-Wunused-variable]
   38 |   VALUE flags;
      |         ^~~~~
database.c: In function ‘exec_batch’:
database.c:726:57: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  726 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), hash_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                         |
      |                                                         int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **) {aka int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:405:9: note: expected ‘int (*)(void *, int,  char **, char **)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **)’ {aka ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)’}
  405 |   int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
database.c:726:81: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  726 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), hash_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                 |
      |                                                                                 VALUE {aka long unsigned int}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:406:3: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}
  406 |   void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
      |   ^~~~~~
database.c:728:57: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  728 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), regular_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                         |
      |                                                         int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **) {aka int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:405:9: note: expected ‘int (*)(void *, int,  char **, char **)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **)’ {aka ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)’}
  405 |   int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
database.c:728:84: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  728 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), regular_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                    |
      |                                                                                    VALUE {aka long unsigned int}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:406:3: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}
  406 |   void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
      |   ^~~~~~
database.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling exception.c
compiling sqlite3.c
sqlite3.c: In function ‘bignum_to_int64’:
sqlite3.c:33:27: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RBIGNUM’; did you mean ‘T_BIGNUM’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   33 | #   define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
      |                           ^~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:35:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘RBIGNUM_LEN’
   35 |   const long len = RBIGNUM_LEN(value);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:33:37: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
   33 | #   define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
      |                                     ^~
sqlite3.c:35:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘RBIGNUM_LEN’
   35 |   const long len = RBIGNUM_LEN(value);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:40:19: error: ‘SIZEOF_BDIGITS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SIZEOF_INT’?
   40 |   if (len > 63 / (SIZEOF_BDIGITS * CHAR_BIT) + 1) return 0;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   SIZEOF_INT
sqlite3.c:40:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sqlite3.c:42:11: error: unknown type name ‘BDIGIT’
   42 |     const BDIGIT *digits = RBIGNUM_DIGITS(value);
      |           ^~~~~~
sqlite3.c:42:28: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RBIGNUM_DIGITS’; did you mean ‘RBIGNUM_SIGN’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   42 |     const BDIGIT *digits = RBIGNUM_DIGITS(value);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            RBIGNUM_SIGN
sqlite3.c:42:28: warning: initialization of ‘const int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
sqlite3.c:43:5: error: unknown type name ‘BDIGIT’; did you mean ‘ISDIGIT’?
   43 |     BDIGIT blast = digits[len-1];
      |     ^~~~~~
      |     ISDIGIT
sqlite3.c:44:5: error: unknown type name ‘BDIGIT’; did you mean ‘ISDIGIT’?
   44 |     BDIGIT bmax = (BDIGIT)1UL << (63 % (CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_BDIGITS));
      |     ^~~~~~
      |     ISDIGIT
sqlite3.c:44:20: error: ‘BDIGIT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ISDIGIT’?
   44 |     BDIGIT bmax = (BDIGIT)1UL << (63 % (CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_BDIGITS));
      |                    ^~~~~~
      |                    ISDIGIT
sqlite3.c:44:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before numeric constant
   44 |     BDIGIT bmax = (BDIGIT)1UL << (63 % (CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_BDIGITS));
      |                           ^~~
sqlite3.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
make: *** [Makefile:245: sqlite3.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/wwboynton/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Try an earlier version of the gem? Try to build from source from the Github repo?

Comment: @Casper I appreciate the suggestion -- An earlier version of the gem (I tried version `'1.3.13'`) actually yields a weird and different error that libsqlite3 is missing entirely. Adding to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seem to have stepped around the problem successfully, albeit not gracefully.

As stupid as it is, I installed the gem on a working native Ubuntu box without issue, and then I copied my rbenv installation of ruby `2.7.4` from that machine over to this one (located at `~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4`), overwriting my local installation of that ruby version completely. Obviously I probably could have just moved gem-specific files and this solution clobbered gems I already had installed, but that's fine. When I ran a `bundle install` on my newly-generated rails project, it installed everything else and used the existing `sqlite3` gem without complaint. When using `irb`, I am able to require the gem without issue.

If some subtle behaviour emerges that shows that this doesn't actually work and just sidesteps the first obvious appearance of the issue, I'll edit or delete this answer. If it appears to work and nobody submits something that fixes the root problem in the next few days, then I'll just accept this answer.